# suma de elementos de dos listas

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo dos listas ejemplo

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista2 = [4,3,2,1]
```

necesito generar una lista3 con los resultados de la suma de cada elemento de ambas que arroje resultado lista3 `[5,5,5,5]`

```
List<int> valor1 = new List<int>();
valor1.Add(1);
valor1.Add(2);
valor1.Add(3);
valor1.Add(4);

List<int> valor2 = new List<int>();
valor2.Add(4);
valor2.Add(3);
valor2.Add(2);
valor2.Add(1);
```

Comment: Hay muchismas formas de conseguir eso. Has intentado algo, y si es así podrías mostrarnoslo?

Comment: Saludos Wladimir, como veo que recién estás iniciando en el sitio, te sugiero revisar esta publicación: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 te ayudará a interactuar de mejor manera :D Por cierto, te comparto una joyita de tutoriales de C# https://www.dotnetperls.com/

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i< list1.Count; i++)
{ 
     list3.Add(list1.ElementAt(i)+list2.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Pero estaría bien que mostraras ¿qué has intentado?, es un simple bucle for donde iteramos a través de los elementos de la lista, se supone que ambas listas tienen la misma longitud. Seguramente puedas hacerlo con un `Select()` pero eso te lo dejo a ti para que lo intentes

Otra manera de hacerlo:

```
lista3 = lista1.Select(e => e+lista2.ElementAt((lista1.IndexOf(e)))).ToList();
```

Explicación:

e es un `placeholder`, es decir un elemento de la `lista1`, entonces el `Select` saca fuera lo que va después de `=>` queremos `e +` un elemento de la `lista2` que tenga el mismo índice que `e`, cuál es el índice de `e? lista1.IndexOf(e)`, si i es el índice `(i= lista1.IndexOf(e))` queremos `lista2.ElementAt(i)` que esto es la solución anterior.

Resultado con limitaciones y a mejorar

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103849/select-issue

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < lista1.Count; i++)
                {
                    lista3.Add(lista1.ElementAt(i) + lista2.ElementAt(i));
                }

solo le cambie el lenght por count y resulto

Answer (score 6):

Dado que ya hay una respuesta aceptada, voy a dejar mi alternativa usando el método de extensión [`Zip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__).

La documentación dice de este método:

> Aplica la función especificada a los elementos correspondientes de dos secuencias, lo que genera una secuencia de resultados.

Lo cual parece exactamente lo que el OP quiere conseguir.

Resumiendo, sería algo tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

```
List<int> valor3=valor1.Zip(valor2, (x,y)=> x+y).ToList();
```

Aplicamos a la primera colección `Zip`, pasando como primer parámetro la segunda colección, y como segundo la función a aplicar. `x` sería un elemento de la primera, e `y` el elemento correspondiente de la segunda.

Comment: Considero que esto sería mas adecuado, esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de hacerlo:

```
lista3 = lista1.Select(e => e+lista2.ElementAt((lista1.IndexOf(e)))).ToList();
```

Explicación:

`e` es un placeholder, es decir un elemento de la `lista1`, entonces el `Select` saca fuera lo que va después de `=>` queremos `e` + un elemento de la `lista2` que tenga el mismo índice que `e`, cuál es el índice de `e`? `lista1.IndexOf(e)`, si `i` es el índice (`i= lista1.IndexOf(e)`) queremos `lista2.ElementAt(i)` que esto es la solución anterior.

Resultado con limitaciones y a mejorar

Comment: ¿Por qué 2 respuestas?, sería mejor editar la que ya te marcaron como aceptada y ahi agregar o quitar información según sea el caso

Comment: porque son dos maneras de hacer lo mismo, utilizando distintas metodologías

Comment: Precisamente compañera debido a la extensión de las mismas considero caben perfecto en una sola publicación